# what is magic values floating in erlang?

Tags: erlang

I am reading [learn you some erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/modules).

In Module chapter, It said:

> macros are mainly useful to avoid having magic values floating around your modules.

But what is magic values floating?

Comment: They probably mean [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in the source.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882